# pygame does not receive scroll event after re-init

Tags: pygame

I'm making a game for school project, and there's scrolling stuffs in my game. I need to reinit pygame to make sure every is reset. But somehow, scrolling stops working after reinit pygame.

I made a simple script to test if that really was the case, and it was.

```py
import pygame

def main():
    while True:
        pygame.init()
        
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1280, 720])
        pygame.display.set_caption("PYGAME DOES NOT RECEIVE SCROLL EVENT AFTER RE-INIT?")
        
        frame = pygame.time.Clock()
        
        running = True
        
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == 1:
                        print("left click")
                    elif event.button == 4:
                        print("scroll up")
                    elif event.button == 5:
                        print("scroll down")
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            frame.tick(30)
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It gets left click event but not the scrolling ones.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` for scroll.

I have found another way for you to map scrollling using `pygame.MOUSEWHEEL`.

Here is the revised code:

```
import pygame

def main():
    while True:
        
        pygame.init()

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1280, 720])
        pygame.display.set_caption("PYGAME DOES NOT RECEIVE SCROLL EVENT AFTER RE-INIT?")
        
        frame = pygame.time.Clock()
        
        running = True
        
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == 1:
                        print("left click")
                    if event.button == 3:
                        print("right click")

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL:
                    if event.y == 1:
                        print("scroll up")
                    if event.y == -1:
                        print("scroll down")

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

            frame.tick(60)
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

btw, happy new year and good luck mate~

Comment: reference for the mouse scroll i found online for additional read:
https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/1665/commits/405667865b99e0ddc5cbba9fb5d813b1f1f21f5a